# Python Trouble Downloading excel file with Dynamic Url with No extension

Tags: python, python-requests

I couldn't find a way to download an excel file using requests module in python the url seems to be dynamic and doesn't have any extensions present. Here's the code:

```
download = requests.get('https://www.djppr.kemenkeu.go.id/page/loadViewer?idViewer=9369&action=download')
with open('file.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(download.content)
```

The output of this code saves only the html code in to the file. Can anyone help me find a proper way to download the excel sheet?

Comment: first you should check what you downloaded - display `download.content`. Maybe you get HTML with some explanation, or maybe it asks for login and password, or maybe it has `JavaScript` code which redirects to different url. `requests` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: I tested this url in web browser and it sends page which redirect to different url. https://www.djppr.kemenkeu.go.id/uploads/files/dmodata/in/5Statistik/6Kepemilikan_SBN_yang_dapat_Diperdagangkan/2021/SBN%20Ownership%20Daily%202021_November%20(1).xlsx . In HTML I see also `<iframe>` with similar url. So you may need to download this page, get url from `<iframe>` and then you can download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check what you get in `download.content` - maybe it sends HTML with some message, or ask for login and password, or have some JavaScript which redirect to file.

You should also check how your url behaves in browser. This way you can also see if it display some HTML.

You could even download file in browser and then you can get from browser real URL for file. And you can see if you can find this url in HTML or if you can find some elements which you could use to generate URL.

---

Your url gives HTML page which has `<iframe>` with `src` which has relative URL to file. So you have to first get HTML, next search `<iframe>` and get relative `src`, next create absolute URL, and next download file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.djppr.kemenkeu.go.id/page/loadViewer?idViewer=9369&action=download'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

src = soup.find('iframe')['src']
print(src)

url = 'https://www.djppr.kemenkeu.go.id' + src

r = requests.get(url)
with open('file.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```